# TFS 2017 Inherit Values from Parent WIT when creating Child

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

When linking a child WIT to a parent in TFS I'd like to copy values from the parent into a child WIT Template. If the parent WIT has a title of xyz and I'm linking a child WIT and creating a new template for it, I want to grab the parent values from certain fields, mainly title.  I think people deciphered my original request but hopefully this is a little cleaner.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  It's a bit unclear what you're asking.  Try adding some more context, some code, and specifically state the problem/error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported.

Copy rule only available within the work item itself:

> You can use the `COPY`, `DEFAULT`, and `SERVERDEFAULT` elements to
>   copy a value from one field to another, copy a server value into a
>   field, or specify a default value to be defined for a field.
>
> ***Source here: [Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/define-default-copy-value-field)***

Parent/Child just links between work items, but no any relationship eachother accross the value of the fileds.